# Show for all n ∈ IN that the inequality $(n!)^2<2^{n^{2}}$ holds (by induction)

Tags: inequality, induction

> Show by induction that$$(n!)^2<2^{n^2} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

1. $n=1 \leftrightarrow  1<2$
2. $(k!)^2<2^{k^2}$
3. $((k+1)(k!))^2 < 2^{(k+1)^2}$ and $(k^2+2k+1)(k!)^2<2k^2 \cdot 2^{2k+1}$, but our assumption told us that, $(k!)^2<2^{k^2}$, therefore I rewrote the inequality to $(k+1)^2<2^{2k+1}$. However, this got me nowhere, I kept doing this for four different inequalities down the line without getting to a satisfying answer.

May I get some help? Please.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: nd what is in the case $$n=0$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner could they possibly define $\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}^+ = \{1, 2, \ldots \}$?

Comment: There's a very cool approach of proving the slightly stronger inequality, $n!\leq 2^{n(n-1)/2}$, by using Vandermonde matrix determinant.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to prove $(k+1)^2<2^{2k+1}$.

- It suffices to prove $k+1\leq 2^k$, since squaring both sides (as $k+1>0$) gives $(k+1)^2\leq 2^{2k}<2^{2k+1}$.
- But binomial expansion $2^k=(1+1)^k=1^k1^0+k1^{k-1}1^1+\dots$ is a sum of $k+1$ nonnegative summands, and just summing the first two summand gives $2^k\geq 1+k$, as long as $k+1\geq 2$ which is indeed what we have in inductive hypothesis.

Comment: I don't comprehend why you take the sum of the first two summand nor what you mean by "as long as k+1≥2 which is indeed what we have in inductive hypothesis." Could you please clearify how this solves the assignment? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by user10354138, we should prove $k + 1 \leq 2^k$ for all $k$. That is, we should prove that $k < 2^k$ for all $k$. If we know that $k < 2^k$, then we also know that $k + 1 \leq 2^k$, and thus $(k + 1)^2 \leq (2^k)^2 = 2^{2k} < 2^{2k + 1}$.

There are multiple ways of doing this. One is using a combinatorial proof. Note that $k = |\{1, 2, ..., k\}|$, and $2^k = |P(\{1, 2, .., k\})|$. Using Cantor's diagonalisation argument that $|S| < |P(S)|$ for all sets $S$ gives us that $k < 2^k$.

Another way of doing this is by another induction. The base case is $k = 0$, in which we see that $0 < 2^0 = 1$ holds.

The inductive step allows us to assume that $j < 2^j$ and tasks us with showing that $j + 1 < 2^{j + 1}$. We see that $j + 1 < 2^j + 1 \leq 2^j + 2^j = 2^{j + 1}$, thus completing the inductive step.

A third way of doing this is by using a certain general fact about increasing functions.

That lemma is as follows:

Suppose $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a function such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(n + 1) > f(n)$. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $f(n) \geq n$.

This lemma can be proved quite simply by using induction. One then applies the lemma to $f(x) = 2^x - 1$ to show that $n \leq 2^n - 1$ for all $n$; hence $n < 2^n$ for all $n$.