# Induction proof for $(n!)^2 < 2^{n^2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

I have had problems on solving this inequality using induction:

$$(n!)^2 < 2^{n^2}$$

for all natural numbers.

I really struggle with inequalities like these. Is there any tips on how to work with them? I tried to multiply with $(n+1)^2$ on both sides in order to get $((n+1)!)^2$ and to then simplify it in some way, but I didnt manage to. In the same way I tried to multiply both sides with $2^{2n+1}$ in order to get $2^{(n+1)^2}$ on the RHS and then simplify. I haven't managed to either way.

I'd really be interested in a solution as I haven't been able to found any out there, and I'd be really thankful if you could share some future tips in order to solve more "complex" inequalities using induction.

Thanks!

Comment: So with one method you would be comparing $2^{2n+1}$ with $(n+1)^2$, correct?  This allows you the option of pausing your primary induction and performing a secondary induction, if necessary.

Comment: Oh okay! I'll try that. But how should I "link" that result to prove my primary induction?

Comment: If you show, for example, $\forall n,2^n \gt n$, then you might form an inequality like $n^2\lt n2^n\lt 2^{2n}$.

Comment: If you prove $\color{blue}{(n+1)^2} < \color{blue}{2^{2n+1}}$ then
$$
(n+1)!^2 = n!^2 \color{blue}{(n+1)^2 }< n!^2 \color{blue}{ 2^{2n+1}} < 2^{n^2}2^{2n+1} = 2^{(n+1)^2}
$$
where on the las inequality you use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show for all n ∈ IN that the inequality $(n!)^2<2^{n^{2}}$ holds (by induction)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927906/show-for-all-n-%e2%88%88-in-that-the-inequality-n22n2-holds-by-induction)

Comment: In the duplicate indicated by @MartinR you can find a more clever way to proceed after induction step!

Comment: If you go from n to n+1, what is the left side multiplied by, and what the right side? As soon as the right side is multiplied by a larger factor, and is larger than the left side, that’s where your induction starts.